# How to test a @Override method inside a @PostConstruct method

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have this method inside my class that I am running my tests on. Below is the code of the method:

```
public class SessionStarter {

    @Autowired
    public Collection<TopicHandler> handlers;

    @Autowired
    private RecoveryManager recovery;

    @Autowired
    private ICoreSessionService iCoreSessionService;

    @Autowired
    private ICoreSessionManager iCoreSessionManager;

    @Autowired
    private ICoreContext iCoreContext;
    
    private volatile String currentSession = null;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        if (!iCoreSessionService.getSessionDirectory().isEmpty()) {
            iCoreSessionManager.addSessionListener(new SessionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSessionStarted(ICoreSessionClient sessionClient) {
                    log.info("Session Started : {}", sessionClient.getSession().getSessionName());
                }
             });
          }
       }
     }
```

Can anyone tell me how to write test code for `onSessionStarted` method and `init` method using Mockito framework? I just need an idea since I am writing test for first time for such a case.

Comment: What you're doing doesn't make sense.  Override is a compile-time annotation whereas PostContruct is run-time.  Override is only there as a flag to verify you're subclass method exists in the parent class or interface.

Comment: This is not my code, I just need to write test for it, and I am not able to figure out how! :(

Comment: Do you just want to test the fact that it logs something? What behaviour are you trying to test? Can you explain what scenario is of interest for you?

Comment: Yes I want to ensure that each and every method is being called and logs are being printed accordingly.

Comment: Consider making the SessionListener implementation a bean (or maybe method reference of bean method), not in-place anonymous class. It will allow to replace it, mock it, use alternatives for testing and so on.

Comment: @Nikolay In my case SessionListener is an interface of ICoreSessionManager Class. Since I dont know how to write test for the Override methods inside init() method, so for now I have only written init() method only for time-being.

Comment: @GregoryJavis replace `new SessionListener() {...}` with new distinct class and instantiate it using Spring bean factories (factory methods). If you need to test it, then it contains some business logic worth to promoting it to a bean.